# Adding a bar to local storage to display in a favorites page:JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have created an application that searches a json file for bars and displays results then i click on each result and am trying to add them to a favourites page using local storage plase can someone help?

//Add Favorites

```js
var barId = $('.thumbnail').attr("id");
$('favoritesbtn').on('click', function() {

  var bars = {
    id: $('.id').attr("id"),
    name: $('#name').text(),
    location: $('#location').text(),
    description: $('#description').text(),
    image: $('#image').attr('src'),
  };

  localStorage.setItem('bars-' + Id,

    JSON.stringify(bars));

  var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bars-' + id));
  console.log('retrievedObject: ', retrievedObject);
});
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Are you getting an error? Is it not being stored?

Comment: I am not getting an error and i am not sure if there is a problem, i think its just not being stored. I am trying to add them to local storage and display them on a favorites page.

Comment: where is `Id` defined?

Comment: I am using a getjson request and the id is a property in that json file.